# VS2017 - Solution lost .csproj reference after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just finished updating Visual Studio 2017 and experienced a odd issue.

When I updated Visual studio, my project was still open. So, when it finished updating it prompted me to recover files which I agreed.

Now, when I open my .sln file, I can't see my project in the solution explorer anymore.

Going through the project folder tree, I can open the .csproj file and everything is there.

How can I re-add my project to my solution so when I open my .sln file everything comes up and why does this happened so i can avoid it next time ?

Comment: always use a source control tool (subversion, git, hg) to track source changes. here you can see diffs and file changes.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I should of specified maybe. I am using git. I was able to find a diff when right-clicking on solution and choosing "compared with unmodified". But I can't edit that fie.

Comment: open file properties of the csproj in File explorer and make sure you have write permissions and "read only" is not set for the file.

Comment: That was very unhealthy, the installer can't update DLLs that are in use.  I seriously doubt that anything named "recover files" could fix that problem.  You ought to select the installer's Repair option to try to fix the problem.  And Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to flame about the installer not forcing you to exit VS.

Comment: I just added the project back by choosing the Add>Exisiting project... Everything is back to normal. That is such a strange behavior that I'd never think that that would be the solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed, I updated VS several times during the course of this project and it always asked me to close it.. Strange.

Comment: Erm, that is *not* strange, it is required.  Did you follow the advice and close VS or completely ignore it?

Comment: @HansPassant Nah you misunderstood me. Sorry. I meant that every other update worked correctly and asked me to close it. What's strange is that this time it didn't.

Comment: I experienced the same thing.  Was able to discard the changes to the solution file using git and reload.